# Why the update 1 is not available?

Tags: 8.1, 8.1-update-1, lumia-635

I have Nokia Lumia 635 with WP 8.1, version 8.10.12397.895.

When I try Phone update it states that my system is in actual state and no updates are available. I have read that Update 1 should be available already.

Why do I not get it?

Comment: I have the same issue..

Comment: Today finally got it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

8.1 Update 1 is part of the [Nokia Denim update](http://lumiaconversations.microsoft.com/2014/09/04/lumia-denim-update/), which is set to roll out to Lumia phones during Q4 of 2014.

Comment: Unfortunaltely it did not.

Comment: Depending on your exact country variant of the your phone, the Lumia 635 has started getting the Denim update over the air, whilst some countries are still on the Cyan version.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your profile and saw you're from the Czech Republic. Microsoft has a page showing the availability for each model per region for new updates. This page can be found here: [**Availability in Europe**](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/availability-in-europe/).

On this page, I didn't find any available updates for the Nokia Lumia 635.

Comment: When Lumia 635 is not in the list, does it mean it will never receive this update? Lumia Cyan stands for Update 1?

Comment: The list of build numbers to release names is [available from the Windows Phone site](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history), and covers all handset manufacturers.