# Why doesn't my phone find the new update?

Tags: update, 8.1-update-1

My phone's OS version is 8.10.12397.895  and according to the [Update History](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history) there is a newer version, the Windows 8.1 Update.

I want to update my phone, so I went to Settings>Phone Update>Check for updates, but it didn't find any new updates:

[image]

How do I update my phone to the newest update?

Comment: What phone, and carrier/region specific model is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/6089/106

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your phone says there's no update and you don't get an error message it means that the update has not yet been enabled for your model-carrier-country combination.

Be aware that updates are rolled out in waves. And even if the update history page tells you there should be an update, from my own experience it can take up to three days until all devices are actually able to.